# Compile most recently compiled document instead of focused one (TeXstudio)

Tags: texstudio

now I recently started working with LaTeX, using TeXstudio. Even more recently, I started working with \include, hence editing external chapters that cannot be compiled on their own.
Unfortunately, it's a bit annoying to switch to my main document each time I want to compile & view. Is there any way for me to compile & view the document that I last compiled & viewed, regardless of the currently focused file?
Note that I know about setting the root document (should work, haven't tried yet), but I'd like to avoid that, in case I'll ever have multiple documents that can be compiled. I don't know, might never happen, but I like to be prepared :)
Also, shortcuts are cool :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378100/106162) is what you want to use.

Comment: that's weird. TeXstudio seems to know which document to compile now? I don't know what was wrong before o.O
//edit: Might be that it now detected the root document correctly? I don't know ._.